# scrlttr2 document fails with datetime2 package

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, datetime2

When using the `datetime2` package in a `scrlttr2` document, I get the error:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime2/datetime2.sty:368:
>   LaTeX Error: \today undefined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. 
>   Type H  for immediate help. ...
>   l.368 \renewcommand*{\today} {%

The code to reproduce this looks like:

```
\documentclass[british]{scrlttr2}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{test}
\opening{Hello}
\today
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

If you take out `datetime2`, the document works fine and `\today` is defined.

The only way I have found to temporarily fix the problem is to call `\newcommand\today{}` before loading `datetime2` but it would be nice to know why I have to.

Comment: Well the first guess is that scrlttr2 defines \today at \begin{document}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah indeed, that seems to be the case. Although, looking at the source, there is also a definition for `\today` not in a `\atBeginDocument{}` but has some conditions attached to it which I don't really understand.

Comment: It's lucky you posted it now (and that I happened to see you question) as I was just about to upload a new version of `datetime2`. I've added a check for `scrlttr2`, and will upload the new version (which will be 1.4) shortly.

Comment: Oh brilliant! Thanks @NicolaTalbot. Perfect timing!

Comment: I've uploaded v1.4, but it make take a few days to get into the distributions.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot looks like the same type of check would be needed for `scrletter` too since this is the new recommended way to create KOMA-letters… thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem stems from `scrlttr2` only defining `\today` at the start of the document (unlike most classes that define `\today` when the class loads). As from v1.4, `datetime2` now checks for `scrlttr2` (and doesn't assume `\today` is already defined). For earlier versions, the following is a temporary fix:

```
\documentclass[british]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{babel}

\def\today{}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\let\orgtoday\today

\begin{document}
\let\today\orgtoday
\begin{letter}{test}
\opening{Hello}
\today
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```